# How to use TCP window scaling to increase throughput on AWS S3 in C++?

Tags: c++, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, tcp, throughput

I am using the [C++ SDK for AWS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-cpp/v1/developer-guide/welcome.html) and would like to increase the per-client throughput of GET requests against AWS S3. I am emphasizing per-client, because otherwise, I would just use the [S3 BitTorrent](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/S3Torrent.html).

According to this [AWS News Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/increasing-s3-d/) it is possible to use TCP Window scaling to increase the amount of data transferred in one go (I think the default is 64 KB).

I did not find any configuration in the [S3 Client](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/cpp/api/LATEST/struct_aws_1_1_client_1_1_client_configuration.html) with which you could change/scale the window.

**Question 1:** Does anyone know how to scale the TCP window size with the C++ SDK?

**Question 2:** Do you have any more tips on how to increase the per-client throughput against S3, without having to pay extra?

Comment: It's probably an operating system setting. Look for OS options, not AWS SDK options.

Comment: Well that would suck, if I would want to do something that is easily deployable

Comment: What platform are you running the S3 Client from?

Comment: Aws Lambda. So I guess my entire idea do use window scaling to increase download speed does not work....

Comment: But this would be interesting to know for any platform. Not just Lambda @jxh

Comment: If you can get a packet capture with `tcpdump` then you can observe whether or not TCP is negotiating window scaling, and how effective the option is for your application.

Comment: Thank you very much for a suggestion, @jxh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is dependent on the type of OS you use and the OS network setting (For example in case of linux it is via sysctl.conf). It is not related to AWS SDK option and hence you may not find an option in AWS SDK.